# Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app_version" (deployment 158)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django application to Beanstalk but my app health is Degraded for some reason. The log file is also deleted automatically so I cannot read the error.
But when I click on "Cause", I get this message:

```
Command failed on all instances.

Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app-fc04-XXXX" (deployment XXX).

Application deployment failed at 2020-07-29T07:24:43Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed.
```

It's also worth noting that the failure is happening when trying to install from requirements.txt, here's the error:

```
Application deployment failed at 2020-07-29T07:24:43Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed.

Collecting alphabet-detector==0.0.7 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/89/c9ab40530fb9142890a79bf39b6f2ee47c311729358794719acd15974e68/alphabet-detector-0.0.7.tar.gz
Collecting argcomplete==1.10.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/82/f44c9661e479207348a979b1f6f063625d11dc4ca6256af053719bbb0124/argcomplete-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I've tried rebooting the instance, deploying an old working version, and deleting the EC2 instance but none of them work.

Comment: Can you login to the EB instance and inspect logs from the inside?

Comment: No, it's also deleted for some weird reason.